# SSRS - listing out CUSTOM data sources?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to change the server for several dozen reports, all developed by different people, that use a mix of:

- Shared Datasources (have a query for this)
- Custom Data Sources in `RDLs` (not perfect but I have a `PowerShell` script that will download all reports, then I can them search them with `Notepad++`)
- Custom Data Sources that are overridden on the `SSRS Server`.

Does anybody have a way to find the details of the Custom Data Sources? Shared is easy. I need to get the details of the CUSTOM.  Tried going through the data sources table but it's not standard `varbinary`.

And hey, bonus fake internet points if you have a way to update the custom `DS` as well; I already have code to change the shared ones.

Comment: When you say Custom Data Source, do you mean setting the DataSource property to the value of an expression?

Comment: Honestly, not sure of the terminology. If I go to "manage" a report, there's a "Custom Data Source" that has a connection string. That can be in the RDL, but can be overridden on the server once the RDL is uploaded.

Comment: Yea, but you will not be able to get that password though.

Comment: That's fine. I just need to make sure that all the reports are looking at the right server alias

Comment: If I recall correctly, those custom data sources are stored in the ReportServer.dbo.DataSource table. Is there anything useful there?

Comment: Yes, two of them.  ConnectionString and OriginalConnectionString, but both are varbinary (0x69651C.... 0xC62E....), but it's obfuscated, doing a CONVERT to either varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) comes up with gibberish.

Comment: I saw that before too. That security certificate (.pfx) that you apply in the configuration for security keys is used under the hood to secure some of the connection/credential information. I hope you find another way:)

Comment: At one time, I though that parsing the .rdl file would yield useful meta information about a custom data source, but it is merely a placeholder of sorts.